# Is there a way to create a project via Youtrack API with a non-standard template?

Tags: youtrack, youtrack-api

I'm trying to create a new project with the Youtrack API. And now I want to create a project with a template that I've created by myself on Youtrack. The API have only "scrum" and "kanban" as possible template parameters. Is there a way to create a project with my own template?

I used this API Call from the Youtrack API documentation site: [Add a New Project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/resource-api-admin-projects.html#create-Project-method)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the name of your template as a parameter:

POST https://username.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/api/admin/projects?fields=name,shortName,id&template=<template_name>

{
"leader": {
"login": "root",
"id": "24-0"
},
"shortName": "MSP",
"name": "Project from REST",
"description": "Template Project"
}